# Where do you need high frequency switching of high AC-currents?

Tags: transistors, relay, mems

Is there any application or piece of electronics that requires high frequency switching of high AC-currents?

Due to the (high) AC-current, application of a transistor would be discouraged while the high switching frequency (or high number of switching-events) would render a relay useless.

Obviously, I can't ask for something that does not exist, but it is possible that extra steps have been taken to make this combination workable, even if it is not ideal.

I'm asking because I'm looking for fields of applications of so-called MEMS-switches, which promise to combine the properties of relays (handle high AC currents) and transistors (frequent or quick switching.)

Edits due to comments:

- I am talking about frequencies >15kHz, since I read [here](https://www.ecstuff4u.com/2019/06/transistor-advantages-and-disadvantages.html#:%7E:text=Disadvantages%20of%20transistor%3A,faulty%20ones%20due%20to%20failure.) that power transistors are not operational above those frequencies.
- I'm aware of RF-MEMS, however, firms such as Menlomicro or Analog Devices came up with MEMS that are rated for currents up to 10 A.
- Regarding the current, I'm talking about currents that typically justify the usage of "power"-transitors. I can't put my finger on a number, since it's probably depend upon the manufacturer and the model.

Comment: Power distribution? Have you considered a Google search?

Comment: Not my field, so this is a wild guess - maybe TX/RX switching for RADAR?

Comment: @SolarMike how does high freq switching occur in power distribution?

Comment: Google failed you?

Comment: "Due to the (high) AC-current, application of a transistor would be discouraged." There are high power transistors such as IGBTs, Thyristors and Triacs

Comment: What frequencies and currents are involved in this?

Comment: MEMS switches are already used, but not for *high* currents, but for radio electronics switching radio frequency signals. What's your definition of *large current*? Would be interested how that works – the first M in MEMS is for "**micro**", and interrupting a high current tends to require quick, **large** separation, due to whatever inductive load (or even just parasitics) there are. Switching a large current leads to large \$\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\$,and with any L in your circuit, that leads to large voltage. If you only plan to switch at \$I=0\$, thyristors have done that for 72 years…

Comment: Voting to close as in need of detail – we really can't tell you applications for "high current, high frequency" anything, without knowing at least in orders of magnitude what "high" means, and why you'd not be using any of the established methods for that particular field.

Comment: The reference is erroneous: transistors are suitable at most any frequency that can be put between wires. In historical context, BJTs first displaced vacuum tubes at low frequencies, the early alloy-junction types having quite low fT. Some modern power BJTs offer fT > 10MHz, and RF types (BJT and MOS) are available up into the 10s of GHz.

Comment: @brans - Last time we looked at MEMs for switching between Tx and Rx for a radar application, they just did not have the lifetime needed.  A typical airborn radar may switch between transmit and receive 10,000/sec.  Over a 20 year time, that adds up to a lot of switching operations.

Comment: 15 kHz is the limit? Maybe in 1960...

Comment: @Rahmany Thyristors and triacs are not transistors.

Comment: @Hearth is it because transistors need to have 3 layers? Or is it because transistors can act as a transconductance amplifier (between on and off region) as well as a switch (fully on/off) ?

Comment: @Rahmany Transistors don't need three layers; JFETs have just two, for instance. Thyristors and triacs are not considered transistors because they don't act like transistors; they have no linear range (that is, they can't be used as amplifiers), and they can't be turned off (other than GTO thyristors, which are very difficult and impractical to turn off but it is technically possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I can't speak for all applications, there is one example I can think of.  Which doesn't use a transistor at all!  I'll use this example to introduce the subject, and then explain why it's relevant.

It seems even today [or nearly?], it is often cheaper to use a *magnetic amplifier* to switch high-frequency AC.  A typical application is the 3.3V supply in most computer PSUs.  (This might not be latest technology these days, but it has been in use for a surprising number of decades, at least.)

The principle of a magnetic amplifier, or more to the point, the saturable reactor at its core -- is to pass AC when no bias current is applied, or some fraction (up to the whole thing) when biased on.  Thus, it acts like a transistor, but with a DC bias controlling an AC flow; the AC of course can be rectified giving a DC output signal, making an ordinary (DC in, DC out) amplifier, and then that output can be used to apply negative feedback to get stable biasing, reduced distortion, controlled gain, etc., or positive feedback to make a latch (memory cell).  All the usual amplifier things we do.

These components are not necessarily the most compact, cheap, or low loss, but it seems they are surprisingly competitive overall.  For reference, the magamp in a typical ATX PSU is about 2cm across, and controls about 100W of output power.

(Aside: come to think of it, I have never, ever seen a datasheet for such a component, let alone any for sale.  The cores, sure, but not the wound component as such.  AFAIK, they are only ever custom made.  So, I certainly don't have a price comparison to support the above claims.)

Anyway, other than that special application, many other magamp applications can be (and have been!) replaced by transistors, either directly, or by redesign.  For example, the 3.3V regulator could substitute the magamp with a transistor and control IC, or replacing the entire circuit with a buck converter -- a more conventional approach nowadays.

Now, this particular example [3.3V regulator] isn't even amenable to MEMS; the magamp is switching on and off every cycle at ~100 kHz.  More generally, magamps switch AC; they have been used for mains power control, for example.  But, again, most applications have disappeared -- mains AC is about the only important control application, and thyristors and inverters have largely taken over here, since the 1960s or so.  (Possibly some very high reliability or long-life (that is to say, old) applications still use them?)

Other AC switching/control applications use inverters instead: controlling HF AC in-transit is surprisingly hard with transistors, but, as complicated as it seems, rectifying to DC then inverting back to AC is surprisingly practical.  This is basically what's happened to power supplies: while you could use phase-controlled or tone-burst gated AC from a free-running, unregulated inverter, it's ultimately cheaper to regulate the inverter output directly, even using multiple inverters if higher performance is required.

As for potential applications where MEMS could be useful -- there aren't many more that would be created from the availability of such components, I think.

The general function is the multiplication of the AC "main" by a control signal.  And for mechanical switches, that multiplication is by very nearly 0 or 1.  In other words, we get amplitude modulation; at least, in a stepwise manner.

We can approximate continuous control by adding many steps together; we could have a "power DAC" with an R-2R network, but using say inductors instead of resistors, to avoid losses.  So we can still have smooth enough control, say to do direct antenna amplitude modulation.

Still, I'm not sure there are many applications that would need a medium power level switch -- commercial AM radio I think would struggle with the high voltages (due to commutation speed and contact arcing), or due to power levels in general (if done at 10 or 20V, the 5kW+ output would require hundreds of amperes!).  And besides, you'd have to justify the change with a drastic improvement in efficiency -- the largest operating cost of AM is electricity.  But they're already quite efficient with class D (switching transistor) amplifiers.  Plus you'd need to convince enough customers that this (relatively) new technology is robust enough to last (minimal servicing / downtime over decades of use).

Most medium/low power applications are already monolithic, so that it doesn't matter how many transistors are required to solve the problem.  Basically any power management, conversion or transmission application has been done by now; perhaps some would've benefited from these switches if they existed say 20 years ago, but it seems far-fetched that new ones would be found.

And at low power levels, they'd be great for RF applications -- RX/TX switching, antenna multiplexing, etc.  But those switches already exist, as it happens!

Finally, to be worth introducing new parts onto the market -- either one *damn good* application has to be found, that a manufacturer is sufficiently confident about to invest in, or it's probably a broad enough application that everyone will benefit, and, well, the applications would be rather more obvious.

So, again, not that this is at all comprehensive, but it seems unlikely that such an application exists, or will be found.  (I, for one, would be interested to hear about it if so!)

Comment: Since you asked about applications: So far I was thinking about replacing TRIACs in dimmers or regulators (such as for ceiling fans). It is not related to AC switching, but the MEMS could operate more efficiently than the TRIAC.

Comment: Also, I found out that switch mode power supply modules use power transistors and that they can struggle with reliability/ lifespan - an issue that MEMS switches such as those introduced by Menlomicro promise to solve.

Comment: AFAIK, semiconductors last essentially forever, if designed appropriately (i.e. low enough operating temperature and current density, to avoid electromigration and such). The biggest wear item is electrolytics, which will be true regardless of the switching technology used. Have heard MEMS can be unreliable due to stiction, but I don't have any experience with them and I don't doubt outright that such problems could be solved.